Website works in Safari but not WKWebView in Xcode
I am building a very simple app for iOS using Swift. I am running Xcode 13, the most recent one that works on Mac Big Sur. It just uses a WKWebView to load my website. My website works flawlessly in Safari however it does not work in the iPhone emulator with WKWebView.
My website is a Blazor server side site using Telerik. The error message is unclear but it appears to not be loading either Telerik or the Blazor server js file. It says it cannot find "TelerikBlazor". I do have JavaScript enabled in my code.
I tried to connect my Mac to my PC via a dev tunnel in Visual Studio but I get "Not allowed to request resource" errors so I can't debug it. But again it works just fine in Safari. I also tried to connect the iPhone emulator in a Maui project to my Mac but it couldn't find Xcode, I assume because it's an older Mac.

"I am running Xcode 3" -- Xcode 3 was released in 2007.

Should be 13, typo

Is your website using https or plain http? By default, App Transport Security only allows apps to make https requests, including any WKWebViews. However, the error message is usually very clear when this is the issue.

It's definitely https
